# 'embedding' wxWidgets in CPropertyPage

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, wxwidgets, cpropertysheet

I am responsible for a fair-sized Windows product with lots of legacy MFC code. I don't have the time to convert the entire product to wxWidgets, but have been implementing new dialogs with wxWidgets. I have the need to update a single tab (CPropertyPage) of a largish MFC dialog (CPropertySheet). In the interests of eventual conversion of the entire product to wxWidgets I'd like to re-implement this one tab with wxWidgets if I can. I haven't found any examples on the web of anyone doing this, but it seems like it should be possible. It seems like the CPropertyPage class could have a single CStatic box which defines the graphic size of the property page. The CPropertyPage implementation would need to instantiate and manage a wxWidgets class that hosts the actual user controls inside the CStatic box. Everything inside the CStatic box would be drawn and managed by wxWidgets class instance, including events. I'm thinking wxPanel would be the appropriate wxWidgets class. Everything on the outside would be managed by the CPropertyPage.

Does anyone see any reason why this cannot work or that it would be enormously difficult? I'm not a specialist in wxWidgets or MFC development, so I'm uncertain. If no one tells me I'm crazy as a loon I'll try and report back what I learn.

TIA for your input,
Alan

Comment: You probably cannot integrate wxWidgets with MFC dialogs. Though I'm not finally sure about this.

Comment: To do it I would need to be a wxWidgets window class that can display a borderless window sans title bar. I would need to be able to prevent the user from directly dragging or resizing the wxWidgets window. The CPropertyPage class would be responsible for configuring the wxWidgets window to display in the correct location and at the correct size. When the user drags or resizes the CPropertySheet window the CPropertyPage class would have to adjust the location and size of the wxWdgets window to match.

Answer (score 0):

An uber-wxWidgets developer says "yes".

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-users/OYyxXzqdoBg